# How can I use a serial connection as an output for a shell?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, tty

I have a serial device (`/dev/ttyACM0`), which is connected to the serial port of a microcontroller. The microcontroller draws text that it gets on that serial connection to a screen. I want to use that screen as a display for a Linux terminal.

I can *sort of* get it displaying the output from commands run on the terminal, but I would also like it to show text that I'm writing in the prompt, as I type it.

So what I want then, is basically for my terminal to not buffer the input, so that it can get sent in realtime, and then also I want the output from the shell to not be buffered either, for the same reason.

I've tried the following:
`unbuffer bash > /dev/ttyACM0`
`unbuffer bash | /dev/ttyACM0`
`stdbuf -i0 -o0 bash > /dev/ttyACM0`

But, none of those worked. The first one outputs text semi-properly, but without allowing me to input anything at all in my terminal on my computer.

The second one gets a permission denied error, even when running as superuser.

The third one allows me to input commands, and outputs text semi-properly as well, but doesn't send the input prompt at all.

Is there any way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to use `/dev/ttyACM0` for the output, but not for the input. Right? A quick improvement to what you already have will be `2>&1` after `>/dev/ttyACM0`, but don't expect to see the cursor.

Comment: that's right, output but not input
i'll try that

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that seems to work pretty much fine! I'll need to get it to ignore escape sequences though
Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe use `col` to filter some escape sequences?